# If Hausdorff distance $d(A,B) < ε$ for some $ε$, where $A,B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are compact, convex subsets does $\dim(A) = \dim(B)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, hausdorff-measure

full question:

The Hausdorff distance between two convex, compact subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as:

$$d(A,B) = \max \{ \max \operatorname{dist}(a,B), \max \operatorname{dist}(b,A) \mid b\in B \text{ and } a \in A\}$$

Prove or disprove that there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that if $d(A,B) < \varepsilon$ then $\dim A = \dim B$ ?

I'm not really sure what does the dimensions of $A$ and $B$ have to do with distance between the two convex sets in this case, we know they are both subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: What does dimension mean?

Comment: Can you find a line segment and a closed disk that are arbitrarily close?

Comment: @mathworker21 dim A should be whatever dimension the set A lives in. if A is a subset of R^3, i guess A could be 1 dimensional, 2 or 3.

Comment: @saulspatz line segment from a in A and b in B? perhaps: ta + (1-t)b for t in [0,1]. im not sure about a disk though, arbitrary close to both sets?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it asks if knowing that the Hausdorff distance between two compact sets is less than some $\epsilon$ guarantees that the sets have the same dimension.  I say no, because whatever $\epsilon$ you give me, I can find a line segment and a disk within $\epsilon$ of one another.  Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Arximede you have not defined dimension. You said you guess A could be 1 dimensional, 2 or 3. How do you determine its dimension?

Comment: @saulspatz you are right about the what the question is asking. but I'm having a hard time understanding your argument. are you saying that if A is a line segment, and B is a disk ? they both satisfy all the conditions, and we can always come up with some epsilon that is greater than the maximal distance (that's what Hausdorff distance is right?).

Comment: @mathworker21 i think for example: let A be a disk and let B be a sphere, and lets say they don't intersect. they are both subsets of R^3, but with different dimensions. in this question, dimension is arbitrary i think.

Comment: No I mean given an $\epsilon$ we can come up with a line segment and a disk that are closer than $\epsilon$.  That's how you prove the contention is false.

Comment: $A = \{0\}$ and $B = B_{2\varepsilon}(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

A space-filling curve ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve ) is constructed as the limit of a sequence of straight-segmented finite chains. The sequence of the (1-dimensional) chains converges (under Hausdorff distance) to a square, a 2-dimensional set. This disproves the statement in the question.

Comment: Even better, given any $\epsilon >0$ and any compact (not necessarily convex) set $C$ in ${\mathbb R}^{n},$ there exists a FINITE set $F$ of points in ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ such that the Hausdorff distance between $C$ and $F$ is less than $\epsilon .$ The OP did not say what notion of dimension is being used (topological, Hausdorff, packing, box, etc.), but $F$ has dimension $0$ for all these variations of "dimension" and $C$ can be chosen to have dimension $n$ for all these variations of "dimension".